# Setting up NextUI with Next.js using TypeScript - CssBaseline missing in @nextui-org/react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, nextui

I can't find any materials to guide me trough the installation using the latest versions of Next.js and NextUI.

The most promissing guide I've found was [this one](https://frontendshape.com/post/install-nextui-in-nextjs-with-typescript).

The only problem is that I'm supposted to do this:
`import { CssBaseline } from '@nextui-org/react'`
But there is no such thing as CssBaseline in @nextui-org/react.

One thing that is also different from the guide is the installation of Next.js - i get asked for a few things during the installation, while there's no such form in the guide. This is the installation form:

```
√ Would you like to use ESLint? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use Tailwind CSS? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use `src/` directory? ... No / Yes
√ Would you like to use App Router? (recommended) ... No / Yes 
? Would you like to customize the default import alias? » No / √ Would you like to customize the default import alias? ... No / Yes
```

I answered 'no' for everything. I also tried again including tailwind but that didn't work either and threw even more errors on top of the missing CssBaseline. I also tried using the App Router, but that changed the app structure so much that the guide can't be followed after that.

I also tried a bunch of youtube guides for this stack, but there was always something different.

Answer (score -1):

The guide you were following is outdated. You should instead follow the official instructions by NextUI [here](https://nextui.org/docs/frameworks/nextjs). The easiest way to set up NextJS, Tailwind, and NextUI is to use the templates they provide:

### App directory

```bash
npx create-next-app -e https://github.com/nextui-org/next-app-template
```

### Pages directory

```bash
npx create-next-app -e https://github.com/nextui-org/next-pages-template
```